# Its redirecting to wallet in apple pay

Tags: react-native, applepay

[Simulator Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgKXI.png)

I am integrating apple pay with stripe.

I have used `tipsi-stripe` package to integrate it.

In simulator it working fine. But when I am trying to test in real device, its direclty redirecting to wallet ask forces me to add new card as I am having credit card already there.

Then if I am adding new card and try to pay nothing happens.

Can any one please guide me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: give me some more details

Comment: First thing I am not getting why its going n wallet, and if its going in wallet then why its not accepting existing card of wallet, and if I am adding new card then why payment is not working with new card as well

Comment: I have attached screen shot of simulator I wanted to work like same